# The best way to manage images when importing from csv in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to know the best way how to handle/manage our products **images** when we import products from csv in Prestashop 1.6. I mean, does Prestashop provide place/space to upload many images? or we must upload in external website (what website)?
May be this question is general enough, but when I googling I dont get the clear answer. Your answers I appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Newer PrestaShop versions support new storage architecture for pictures. This new system of image placement allows to work with images much faster, keeping them in order. Images are stored at /img/p folder, in created subfolders that correspond to image ID

Basically, you will avoid having 100,000 pictures in the same “/img/p” folder. Instead, the pictures will be placed into subfolders within “/img/p” directory *(e.g.: “/img/p/1/2/ for image with ID 12 or /img/p/7/6/5/4/7 for image with ID 76547).*

Comment: thanks for your answer Maria. What version do you mean? Is version 1.6 has that system of image placement? Then in what menu I can find that?

Comment: In PrestaShop 1.6 the images are placed to img/p subdirectory. So to find where images uploaded at your server you need to log in with FTP credentials using FileZilla, Total Commander or any other FTP client, then you will see your store folders and one of them will be store root (usually public_html but might be other). In store root folder you will find tmp folder, then 'p' directory and then subdirectories on the basis of image ID as I have described above.
This way you can find placement of your images, as PrestaShop offers the place for storing, so I guess you don't need external website.

Comment: Oh thanks so much Maria, I know perfectly. Nice explanation ;)

Comment: I have also written the article on how to optimize images working with PrestaShop, you may find it helpful - https://www.prestashopmanager.com/useful-articles/about-prestashop/3-simple-must-dos-for-optimizing-your-prestashop-store/